# If else vs ifelse

Tags: java, coding-style

what's the difference between the below two, are they both one and the same?

```
     if(condition){
            //code
      }else{
         if(condition){
            //code
         }
     }





    if(condition){
         //code
     }else if(condition){
        //code
     }
```

Comment: else if is more clear to read. you do not have extra indent

Comment: Some people like the `{}` and use them everywhere - in Perl there is no choice. There is no difference in your code.

Comment: down voter, can you please explain the reason for down voting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important difference is that the first one looks like this:

```
if(condition){
       //code
} else {
    if(condition) {
       //code
    }
}
```

and the second one looks like this:

```
if (condition) {
     //code
} else if (condition) {
    //code
}
```

Since they are syntactically equivalent, clarity and appearance are the most important issues when deciding which to use. If you keep looking at each one in turn a few times, you'll see why the second is preferred in almost any language where both are equally usable. :D

Comment: Actually, they are syntactically distinct. They are _semantically_ equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

They are exactly the same, except the first one *allows* you to introduce code in the `else` part that is not affected by the second `if` condition.

Answer (score 3):

They're the same.  The second way is more common and preferred, because the first way suggests that the code is more complex (more deeply nested) than its logic really requires.

Answer (score 1):

They both work the same.

```
else if {
```

Is generally more readable, because it avoids deep nesting.

Answer (score 1):

Both these are same but in the first case :

```
if(condition){
            //code
      }else{  
         if(condition){
            //code
         }
     }
```

You evaluate inside  the else statement with the if condition.
You cannot add a final (default) else in this.

But in the second case you can add an else part as the default part.

I prefer the second one.